# How to pick two different images from gallery seperately in the same activity and load them into their imageviews at different clicks?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Am building a mobile app for our local football team.I want to able to pick the logo images for the two teams that will have an upcoming game.
So picking the images from the Gallery and save them.

I have created the openGalleryMethods to open Gallery and then onbtain the image that is selected at the first pick.
Then call the openGallery Method again and pick the image that is picked the second time on another imageView.

public class MatchFixturesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private EditText HostTeamInput,VisitingTeamInput,
            StadiumHostingGame,LeagueOfPlay,DateOfGameDisplay;
    private CircleImageView HostTeamLogo,VisitingTeamLogo;
    private TextView DisplayTimeOfGame;
    private Button TimeOfGameBtn,DateOfGameBtn,SavingInfoButton;
    private static final int GalleryPick = 1;
    private static final int GalleryPick2 = 1;
    private Uri ImageUrl1,ImageUrl2;
    private String HostTeamName,VisitingTeamName,StadiumHostName
            ,LeagueName,DateOfPlayInput,TimeInput,RandomKey,downloadImageUrl,downloadImageUrl1;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_match_fixtures);



    HostTeamLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            OpenGallery();
        }
    });

    VisitingTeamLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            OpenGallery1();
        }
    });

}

private void OpenGallery() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GalleryPick);
}
private void OpenGallery1() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GalleryPick);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GalleryPick  && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){
        ImageUrl1 = data.getData();
        HostTeamLogo.setImageURI(ImageUrl1);
    }else{
        ImageUrl2 = data.getData();
        VisitingTeamLogo.setImageURI(ImageUrl2);
    }


}
```

}

I expect the logo of the hosting team to be loaded into the imageview at first pick and then the second pick the logo for the visitong team to be loaded in its se[erate imageView

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank and fortunately have got the answer. I had to define my GalleryPicks as 
GalleryPick and GalleryPick1 and defined as
    private static final int GalleryPick = 1;
    private static final int GalleryPick2 = 2;
With this,every thing worked perfectly well with the same code